# javascript runing error when from visual studio localhost say check proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a problem wth running from visual studio using internet explorer specially chrome could not  run localhost
[image]

I have tried by resetting by netsh int ip reset as well as some other

Comment: First of all - you cannot run javascript directly in browser... you need to embed it in HTML

Comment: Second - share screenshot of your VSCODE and CMD Screen...

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot run a javascript file directly in a browser**

One solution may be

Create an  HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
     <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> //Import any CSS if needed
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="pageBody"> 
      </div>
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

In JS

```
document.getElementByID('pageBody').innerHTML += <span>Some text goes here</span>
```